# Date filter not converting string formated date

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

From Backend side I was getting String formatted date in the form of 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS' format inside response.
I have to show last contact date of all users on template so I have applied ng-repeat and in interpollation I tried to bind {{lastContactedDate | date: "yyyy-mm-dd"}} but it will not filtered the correct date

example- I was getting lastContactedDate as "20230620131921" from backend when I tried to bind on portal with date filter it prints 2611-01-31 (yyyy-mm-dd) formated

Could you plz sugest me the correct approch to convert or filter the date ?

lastContactedDate as "20230620131921"
 {{lastContactedDate  | date: "yyyy-mm-dd"}}

It should print 2023-06-20